# C++ Sockets - Returning single addrinfo from array of strcutures

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

It's been ages since I've worked with C++ so this is probably a basic issue but I just can't seem to find a solution.

I need to write a small C++ sockets class that can look up IP addresses for a given host/port. Everything works fine inside of the class although I'm not sure how to return a single addrinfo structure (I've marked the line below) from the array of structures to the calling function.  I've tried memcopy, pointers, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Getaddrinfo returns an array of address structures (m_addList). When compiled/run, the results inside the class are completely different from those returned. Please note that  for the sake of simplicity I've simplified the example.

```
./lookup www.stackoverflow.com 80
=> 2
=> 1
-> 32767
-> 4197087
```

The values marked with "=>" are correct and can be used to generate sockets, although the "->" values are incorrect causing a socket error.

Code:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class getAddress
{
private:
    struct addrinfo *m_addList;  // List of returned address info structures
public:
    int getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo singleAddress);
};

int getAddress::getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo singleAddress)
{
    int ret;
    struct addrinfo addCriteria;

    memset(&addCriteria, 0, sizeof(addCriteria));
    addCriteria.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    addCriteria.ai_socktype =  SOCK_STREAM;
    addCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &addCriteria, &m_addList);
    if (ret != 0)
        return -1;

    // Simply return the first address found
    singleAddress = *m_addList;                // <---- This is my problem
    cout << "=> " << singleAddress.ai_family << endl;
    cout << "=> " << singleAddress.ai_socktype << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int res;
    struct addrinfo inVal;

    if (argc < 3)
        cout << "Usage: main [domain] [port]" << endl;

    getAddress adObj;
    res = adObj.getAddressInfo(argv[1], argv[2], inVal);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        cout << "-> " << inVal.ai_family << endl;
        cout << "-> " << inVal.ai_socktype << endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You are passing the third parameter by value. Whatever value you assign to SingleAddress will be assigned to the copy. The source will remain inatct, thus the random numbers you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
int getAddress::getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo &singleAddress)
```

As it is now, you are only modifying a local copy of `singleAddress`, and are doing nothing with `inVal`

Comment: I changed the function and its prototype to &singleAddress and it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo singleAddress);
```

You cannot return a value from a function in a parameter passed to that function by value. `singleAddress` is a local variable of `getAddressInfo`. You can modify it however you want, the caller will not see any of it.

You need to get familiar with passing parameters by reference/by pointer.